# Iterate sorted list and count distinct numbers

Tags: c++, list, unique, counting

I want to iterate a sorted list to get the number of distinct numbers.

Please find my attempt to implement this below. The size of the list is `k*k`.
As the list is sorted, I compare consecutive items to identify duplicates.

```
int count_distinct(list<int> v)
{
    int num = k*k;
    std::list<int>::iterator it;
    it = v.begin();
    for (int a=0; a<k*k-1; a++)
    {
        if(*it == *it+1)
            num--;
        it++;
    }

    return num;
}
```

I can't change the list, so `std::list::unique()` is not an option. Making a copy of the list or the unique items is too slow for it being useful to me.

Comment: `k++`? Are you sure about that?

Comment: `for (const auto num : v)` iterates the list. Then use a `std::map<int, int>` for the result and count up the `int` at the `num` index.

Comment: Is the input list sorted?

Comment: @JesperJuhl If we only want to count distinct numbers, a `set<int>` would work.

Comment: Where is `k` defined?  Why are you taking `v` by value instead of const reference? Is `v` sorted or not?  If not, you need to sort a copy with `std::list::sort`.  Then use `std::distance(std::unique(sorted.begin(), sorted.end()), sorted.end());`

Comment: @melpomene true, but I got the impression that OP wanted to know how many of each district digit there is - I might be wrong.

Comment: just add all of them to set<int> and you will have the values and they will be unique

Comment: If the list is not sorted, then I think `std::set` is the best approach.  If it is, then probably counting the elements by hand is best.

Comment: If you want fast then consider using `std::vector` rather than `std::list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has following problems:

1. You pass container by value to the function. You should pass it by const reference to minimize speed and memory loss.
2. Your condition `*it == *it+1` is always false (you compare `n` and `n+1`). Probably you wanted to write `*it == *(it+1)` but `std::list` has [bidirectional iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) and you cannot `+1` them.

The code should be like this:

```
size_t count_distinct(const std::list<int>& l) {
    if (l.empty()) return 0;

    size_t distinct = l.size();
    auto prev = l.begin();

    for (auto cur = std::next(prev); cur != l.end(); ++cur, ++prev) {
        if (*cur == *prev)
            --distinct;
    }

    return distinct;
}
```

Or you can write your modified version of `std::unique` algorithm:

```
template<class ForwardIt>
size_t unique_cnt(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last) {
    if (first == last)
        return 0;

    size_t distinct = 1;    
    ForwardIt prev = first;

    while (++first != last) {
        if (!(*prev == *first)) {
            ++distinct;
        }
        prev = first;
    }
    return distinct;
}
```

And then simply use it

```
size_t distinct = unique_cnt(l.begin(), l.end());
```

There is also an `std::unique_copy` + custom iterator approach, but it doesn’t look elegant enough.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `std::set`  to grab unique elements count ?

```
size_t count_distinct(const list<int>& v)
{    
    std::set<int> temp (v.begin(), v.end());

    return temp.size(); 
}
```

Comment: @Galik Opps yeah, I just blinding copied OP's snippet.

Comment: @DAle You can provide one if you have something in mind

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to find the number of unique integers in that list, and the list is not sorted, you could use a temporary set or unordered_set like this:

```
size_t count_distinct(list<int> v)
{
    std::unordered_set<int> distinct;
    for(auto &x : v)
    {
        distinct.insert(x);
    }
    return distinct.size();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for extracting a container of all unique values 
(since you said you wanted to use them afterwards):

A method to **count** unique values:

```
template < typename T >
size_t count_unique(const std::list<T> & input)
{
    std::set<T> unique(input.begin(), input.end());
    return unique.size();
}
```

A method to **extract** a list of unique values:

```
template < typename T >
void unique(const std::list<T> & input, std::list<T> & output)
{
    std::set<T> unique(input.begin(), input.end());   
    std::copy(unique.begin(), unique.end(), std::back_inserter(output));
}
```

A sample program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::list<int> list = { 1, 3, 4, 10, 3, 1, 6, 7 };
    std::list<int> out;

    std::cout << count_unique(list) << std::endl;

    unique(list, out);
    for (auto & x : out)
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For sorted data, you will probably not get much more efficient than the straight-forward approach that you attempted to implement.

I'd prefer to have something along the lines of this, as I find it more intuitive to count upwards instead of down:

```
std::size_t count_unique_sorted(std::list<int> const& l) {
    if (l.empty()) return 0;
    std::size_t count = 1;
    auto previous_value = l.front();
    // TODO: hope that the compiler fixes that redundant first comparison...
    for (auto next_value : l) {
        if (next_value != previous_value) {
            // the value changed! increment count and update previous_value
            ++count;
            previous_value = next_value;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

You can also make the [`std::unique_copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy) algorithm to count instead of copy, by providing a custom OutputIterator. But this will have little benefit performance-wise versus the approach presented above. Maybe it will be worth revisiting, when the [parallel implementations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism) of the algorithms from C++17 become available though.

Here's an example:

```
template <typename T>
struct counter : public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, T> {
    explicit counter(std::size_t& count) : count(count) {}
    counter& operator*() { return *this; }
    counter& operator++() { return *this; }
    void operator=(T const&) { ++count; }
private:
    std::size_t& count;
};

std::size_t count_unique_sorted2(std::list<int> const& l) {
    std::size_t count = 0;
    std::unique_copy(l.begin(), l.end(), counter<int>(count));
    return count;
}
```

Note that in both cases you would want to pass the list as a const reference and not as a copy into the function.

If you feel like this is still to slow, feel free to explore the joys of parallelization. Benefits of this will probably depend on data volume and distribution. So you should start some systematic profiling by then.

Unless you need to reorder the values a lot, consider to dump your data into a `std::vector<int>` in the first place. Having random access iterators simplifies things and having better locality may also speed things up...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::list<int>::unique()` to get all distinct elements in `v` and `size()` to count them. `v` must be sorted. Check if `v` is sorted using function std::is_sorted(). If not - sort it. It also means that `count_distinct` does not work for const list objects.

```
size_t count_distinct(list<int>& v)
{
    if (!is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end()))
    {
        v.sort();
    }
    v.unique();
    return v.size();
}
```

Comment: You should add a note, that the input is required to be sorted and that it doesn't work on a const list.

Comment: The result should be `size_t`, not `int`

Comment: You should add `std::is_sorted` to the answer, and if not sorted, use `std::sort` to make this answer correct